# Json Parsing For Android Studio With Php Codes

Tags: php, android, json

I already saw a lot of tutorial regarding Json parsing and Php. I still can't keep up with those tutorials because I can't find any simplified Json parsing tutorial or some of them can't achieve my expected output or am I that slow to learn it? It will be enough for me if anyone can give me links tutorial for total noob with Json Parsing with Php using hotspot no webservice. TIA

Comment: Asking for a tutorial and other educating materials is off-topic at SO, sorry. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

to parse Json Data best api is Google Gson and usefull it very easy
use this link : https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I really appreciate the response, I edited my question I'm actually looking for a very easy to follow Json tutorial. Anything that you can suggest?